# In Unity3d how can I move a gameobject with mouse while interacting with physics engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to develop a 3d game. An "air hockey" simulator. I would like to control the paddle with the mouse but at the same time, I would like to use the physics engine to handle collisions with the puck and the borders of the table.

I tried the following:

- If I use a Kinematic paddle I lose the property to handle the physics by the engine.
- If I use static object the same.
- If I use a dynamic rigidbody I am not able to control smoothly the paddle.

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes a air-puck feel good is the sliding effect it has. Ofcourse it doesn't continue forever, but still feels nice.

Here is what you can do:

1. Create an Paddle & Puck
2. Create two physics materials for both.
3. Decrease the friction on the material that both feels slidey, the puck a little more than the paddle.
4. For both:

   - Freeze the x & z rotation
   - Freeze the y position

Now the part that makes the paddle use physics & RigidBody correctly. Create a new script for moving the paddle:

```
public class PaddleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RigidBody rb;
    
    public float speed = 5;
    public float minDist = 0;
    public float maxDist = 5;
    public LayerMask layers;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        // Paddle will only move if we hold down the mouse button
        paddleGrabed = Input.GetInput(KeyCode.Mouse0);
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (paddleGrabed)
        {
            HandleMovement();
        }
    }
    
    void HandleMovement()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.MousePosition);
        RaycstHit hit;
        
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f, layers))
        {
            // Calculate the slow effect as paddle comes close to the point;
            float dist = Vector3.Distance
            (
                new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0 transform.position.z),
                new Vector3(hit.point.x, 0, hit.point.z)
            );
            
            dist = Mathf.Clamp(dist, minDist, maxDist);
            var slowEffect = dist / maxDist;
            
            // Now move move the rigid body appropriately
            var dir = new Vector3(hit.point.x, 0, hit.point.z) -new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0 transform.position.z);
            dir.Normalize();
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + dir * slowEffect * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

That should move the Paddle to a certain position with a bit of a lag and sliding effect.

Comment: Thank you CorrieJanse, later I will try it.  Just a question: the paddle rigid body should be a kinematic one?

Comment: @ilBarra, I would not. Currently it moves when you hold down Mouse0, but If you move quickly you might be able to kinda slide it. Haven't tested it out but think it should work. If you use kinematic then it won't bounce of the walls